# How can I get the errors of an individual field in Symfony2 twig template?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

Normally, we can have the Symfony Form to output the field errors using the form_errors twig function, but how can we get the specific errors of an individual field, but not display it?
Or is there any way that we can examine if one field has errors or not?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're looking for `form.fieldname.vars.errors`. If you want to check if a form field has errors or not, use the `length` filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can render error for individual field types. Check [Customizing Error Output](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#customizing-error-output) section of Form rendering cookbook entry.